# Every element of field $F_q$ has $k$th root if and only if $\gcd(q-1,k)=1$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Help me please to prove that:

> For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ each element of field $F_q$ is the $k$-th power of some element from that field if and only if $GCD(q-1, k)=1$.

#### My approach

Let's look at multiplicative group of that field $F_q^*$. That group is cyclic, so it has $q-1$ elements and they all generated by some element $\alpha$. So, $F_q^*$ looks like $\{\alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{q-1}\}$. If we raised them all to the power $k$, we'll get $\{\alpha^{k}, \alpha^{2k}, \dots, \alpha^{(q-1)k}\}$. Now we need to prove that all that raised elements are different if and only if $GCD(q-1,k)=1$. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Work. Please. Show.

Comment: Do you know that the multiplicative group is cyclic?

Comment: Let's look at multiplicative group of that field $F_q^*$. That group is cyclic, so it has $q-1$ elements and they all generated by some element $\alpha$. So, $F_q^*$ looks like $\{\alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{q-1}\}$. If we raised them all to the power $k$, we'll get $\{\alpha^{k}, \alpha^{2k}, \dots, \alpha^{(q-1)k}\}$. Now we need to prove that all that raised elements are different if and only if $GCD(q-1,k)=1$.
But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a non-zero element of $F_q$. If $k$ and $q-1$ are relatively prime, there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $ks+(q-1)t=1$ (Bezout). So 
$$x^1=(x^s)^k(x^{q-1})^t=(x^s)^k.$$

For the other direction,  show that if the gcd of $k$ and $q-1$ is not $1$, then the map that takes $t$ to $t^k$ is not one to one.

Comment: But, for other direction, should't I prove exactly that if gcd is 1 then the map is one to one?

Comment: And why $(x^{q-1})^{t}=1$?

Comment: The multiplicative group of non-zero elements has order $q-1$, and always the order of an element divides the order of the group. We don't need to know the group is cyclic. But if you want to use that, then $x=\alpha^k$ for some $k$, so $x^{q-1}=(\alpha^{q-1})^k$.

Comment: @FunkyCat:  For the *first* direction, the one I used Bezout on, one can alternately prove that if the gcd is $1$, then the map is one to one. Actually, it is easier to show it is onto, for which there is a simple Bezout argument closely related to the displayed equation in the answer above.